# Save checkbox status using JavaScript in JSP file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveLastCheck() {
        var getStstus = localStorage.getItem("LineOp");

        if (getStstus === "true")
            $("#LineOp").prop("checked", true);

        $("#LineOp").click(function(){
            localStorage.setItem('LineOp', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });
    }
</script>

<input type='checkbox' id='LineOp' />
```

My question is: **why does this code not work in a JSP file, but when I try to use in [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/VPC86/1/) it works?**

I had even try to give `onclick`, `onchange` method to the `input`, but nothing was worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Have you tried to see what value is been saved/restored? Where/When do you call the function `SaveLastCheck()`?

Comment: <input type='checkbox' id='LineOp' onclick="SaveLastCheck()" /> here.I looked in the java console for observing errors but I do not see any, maybe method "SaveLasCheck()" is not called.

Comment: It will work if you call it in the `$(document).ready` instead, because you are associating the click behavior inside of it, and also the logic of how the checkbox will behave. Your fiddle is not accurate to the problem because all the logic is applied `onload` and is not wrapped in the `SaveLastCheck()` function. This is the real behavior that you are getting on JSP: http://jsfiddle.net/b3g6arbd/ (not working), and this is how it should be as I explained above: http://jsfiddle.net/b3g6arbd/1/ (working)